# Why am I receiving an Invalid Form Body error with Discord API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot but when I create a ping command it says the following:

```
(node:37584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body
embed.footer.icon_url: Scheme "flashybot" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
embeds[0].footer.icon_url: Scheme "flashybot" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\niels\Documents\VsCode Projects\Discord Bots\FlashyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:154:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\niels\Documents\VsCode Projects\Discord Bots\FlashyBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:39:14)
    at async callback (C:\Users\niels\Documents\VsCode Projects\Discord Bots\FlashyBot\commands\misc\ping.js:15:21)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:37584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:37584) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

My code for ping.js is:

```
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")

module.exports = {
    commands: ["ping", 'pong'],
    expectedArgs: "",
    permissionError: '',
    minArgs: 0,
    maxArgs: null,
    callback: async(message, args, text, client) => {
        let pinging = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Pinging....')
            .setColor("RED")
            .setFooter(client.user.avatarURL(), client.user.username)

        const msg = await message.channel.send(pinging)

        let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Pong! ')
            .addField("Api Latency", `${Math.floor(message.createdTimestamp - message.createdTimestamp)}ms`)
            .addField("Latency", `${Math.floor(client.ws.ping)}ms`)
            .setColor("LIGHT_GREEN")
            .setFooter(client.user.avatarURL(), client.user.username)
            .setTimestamp()

        msg.edit(embed)
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with this? I tried doing message.client.user.avatarURL() and also the displayAvatarURL() function but it keeps giving this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logs say
 `embed.footer.icon_url: Scheme "flashybot" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https'). embeds[0].footer.icon_url: Scheme "flashybot" is not supported. Scheme must be one of ('http', 'https').`
Which seems to indicate the url provided for your icon is incorrect (and does not start with http or https which is required).

I assume this is client.user.avatarURL() which is incorrect, try to replace it with a hard coded picture link and see if it helps. You may have an incorrect value in avatarURL...